# iphone social networking

Tags: iphone, servlets

I am trying to build an application which should send the data as an xml file to the server and other user's should be able to see the info uploaded by another user.
Embedding everything in xml file is done but now the question is how to push this information to the other user's so that they can see it in a particular format. Also how i can proceed towards making my own server to support this iphone app.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably using a loop in your iPhone to check for new data every 1-2 minute. iPhone app can call your service to check if there is new information, if it doesn't have, you return a code to tell. If it has new information, you return the new information under a specific format.

The server and iPhone app has to agree on the same xml format